# Get substring from regex

Tags: objective-c, regex

Need to write a generic code (not any if and else condition) where it'll return substring for Output format regex1 and regex2 and etc...

Input format regex = `[A-Z0-9a-z]+-{1}[A-Z0-9a-z]+` (alphanumeric-alphanumeric)
Input string = `ABC123DEF-2323GHIJ`

Output format regex1 = `[A-Z0-9a-z]+`
Output format regex2 = `[A-Z0-9a-z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]+`

Same code it has to return for the below queries

1. Input string = `ABC123DEF-2323GHIJ` Output format regex1 = `[A-Z0-9a-z]+`
2. Input string = `ABC123DEF-2323GHIJ` Output format regex1 = `[A-Z0-9a-z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]+`
3. Input string = `ABC123DEF-2323GHIJ` Output format regex1 = `[A-Z0-9a-z]`

I have tried using build in functions like `matchInStrings`, `firstMathcings`, `componentSeparatedByString` and etc... But at some point i have to say index position.

Have thought it's not possible to make generic code for my requirement, still i wanted to post here to get some idea.

plist format

```
{
    "Input format" = "[A-Z0-9a-z]+-{1}[A-Z0-9a-z]+";
    "Output format" = "[A-Z0-9a-z]+";
}
```

Comment: why cannot you use `if..else..`? is it a kind of homework?

Comment: Because i have thousands of input format, it's not good to have thousands if right?

Comment: no one said there is a problem with any `if..else..` branch. those branches are essential parts.